# Low-level Router from React-Router-Dom only navigates to new URL but doesn't render components

Tags: reactjs, react-router

First of all, I'm a beginner in the world of Typescript and React, so please bear with me.

The issue I have is whenever I navigate using e.g. buttons rendered as "NavLink" or "Link" from the `react-router-dom` package, the result is only the URL changes, and nothing gets rendered.

If I press enter on the address bar (forcing to run given URL), the components render, otherwise it's only my apps background I can see.

The difference with all the other questions I could find here on SO and other sites is that I'm not using high-level `BrowserRouter` but `Router`, so that I'm able to use `createBrowserHistory()` and pass it to the router, as well as use it from MobX when needed.

The weirdest thing is - I have used the same code in another application for routing and it works fine. The version of react-router was 5.1.3 there, now I have 5.1.5, so I suppose it's something else I do not see.

What is even weirder - if I switch to `BrowserRouter` instead of the low-level one, everything works fine - it seems like there is maybe some issue with the `history` package I'm using?

**index.tsx:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import "./app/layout/styles.css";
import App from './app/layout/App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';

export const history = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={history}>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

**App.tsx:**

```
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite";
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import {
  Route,
  RouteComponentProps,
  Switch,
  withRouter,
} from "react-router-dom";
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import { Container } from "semantic-ui-react";
import CheckinAuthorize from "../../features/checkin/CheckinAuthorize";
import CheckinDetails from "../../features/checkin/CheckinDetails";
import HomePage from "../../features/home/HomePage";
import NavBar from "../../features/nav/NavBar";
import NotFound from "./NotFound";

const App: React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = ({ location }) => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
      <Route
        path={"/(.+)"}
        render={() => (
          <Fragment>
            <ToastContainer position='bottom-right'/>
            <NavBar />
            <Container style={{ marginTop: "7em" }}>
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
                <Route exact path="/checkin" component={CheckinAuthorize} />
                <Route path="/checkin/:id" component={CheckinDetails} />
                <Route component={NotFound} />
              </Switch>
            </Container>
          </Fragment>
        )}
      />
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default withRouter(observer(App));
```

**Example on how I use NavLinks:**

```
import React from "react";
import { Menu, Container } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const NavBar: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Menu fixed="top" inverted>
        <Container>
          <Menu.Item header as={NavLink} exact to="/">
            <img
              src="/assets/logo.png"
              alt="logo"
              style={{ marginRight: "10px" }}
            />
            Home
          </Menu.Item>
        </Container>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
};

export default observer(NavBar);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently it was related to the 'history' package.

I removed the history package I previously installed (did `yarn remove history`), and everything started to work for me. Seems I was overactive with adding this package to my project. Now the import points to `node_modules/@types/history/index`, which I didn't install explicitly, probably a dependency.

Even though the question is not really related to the answer, I will leave it as is - maybe someone will have the same issue and will stumble upon it. I wish I had such possibility :)

Answer (score 0):

Such problems can be ignored by switching to BrowserRouter, but just to make sense about the actual problem. This is for those guys who really wanna use the low level Router. The problem is with the history package that you have installed.
Try using the prior versions like 4.7.2 which lets your import default export createHistory from history/createBrowserHistory instead of the latest ones which imports named export createBrowserHistory from history directly.

From what i experienced the latest history lets your change routes only on page refresh and also for navlink or link it doesn't maches any routes just changes the url.

well thats all hope its helps someone.